# how to reload UIcollectionView data properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a default UIImage array and name array for the label and the imageView in my `collectionView` cell. `UIcollectionviews` data won't change after i call the `reloadData()` function and change my default sources for the label and imageView, unless i scroll each cell out of the screen and scroll back to see the data have changed.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mycollectionview: UICollectionView!

var castNames = ["", "", "", "", ""]

var collectionviewimages = [UIImage(named: "pic"), UIImage(named: "pic"), UIImage(named: "pic"), UIImage(named: "pic"), UIImage(named: "pic")]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return castNames.count

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
    "customcell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.Initialize(image: collectionviewimages[indexPath.row]!, name: 
    castNames[indexPath.row])

    return cell
    }
}
```

by tapping a button i get back some Json and parse it to change the default data sources of the `collectionView`. after altering ot the way i want i call this func:

```
mycollectionview.reloadData()
```

Comment: Provide more code. Specifically where you parse your data and call `mycollectionview.reloadData()`

Comment: Chances are that you're calling `reloadData` in a background thread.

Comment: @TomasJablonskis i am sure of my new data befor calling the reloadData() . I printed the new array and got back what i expected. my problem is with the way the new data appears.

Comment: the label on the cell only changes when its dequeued and scrolled out of screen

Comment: have you set collectionview datasource and delegate = self

Comment: Put a breakpoint in "cellForItemAt" function to see the delegate work or not.

Comment: @antonioyaphiar yes i have

Comment: Have you assigned new data in `self.castNames = //New Array` ?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR yes rajesh. I get my new data in a JSON format and then i parse the data to form my new castNames array

Comment: @kamrandehghan Can you send me your project?

Answer (score 0):

Always use reload Collectionview on main thread.

```
dispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.mycollectionview.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

collectionView.delegate = self

collectionView.datasource = self

Comment: already done. I believe collectionview won't load without these 2.